# How do I create a toggle-able input disabler in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, input, toggle

If the title didn't describe my question great enough, this is what I want to create: a input that I can disable/enable with a button. This is what i have done so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Toggle-able input</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="myFile">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Enable/disable</button>
</body>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    if (x.disabled === false) {
      x.disabled = true;
    } else {
      x.disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Next time use the `<>` snippet editor, click TIDY and see the reason immediately: Missing end bracket

Comment: I vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close your function properly

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");

    if (x.disabled === false) {
      x.disabled = true;
    } else {
      x.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Toggle-able input</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myFile">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Enable/disable</button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="text" id="myFile">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Enable/disable</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");

    if (x.disabled === false) {
  x.disabled = true;
}

else {
  x.disabled = false;


}
} // << You were missing this. 

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myFile">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enable/disable</button>

<script>
var togg = true;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myFile").disabled = togg;
    togg = !togg;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```